# Use modal bootstrap as delete prompt in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Hello everyone I use the Modal as a delete prompt on my CI script but its not working maybe there is an error on it. Anyone can check the codes for me.

My codes on delete button:

```
<a onclick="confirm_modal(<?php echo base_url('threads/deletereplytopic/'.$toprep['id']) ?>)" style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#deleteReplyTopic"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

And my Codes in Modal an Js:

```
<!-- Delete Topic Reply  Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteReplyTopic" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h6 class="modal-title"><?php echo lang_key('confirm_delete'); ?></h6>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php echo lang_key('confirm_delete_text'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class="btn btn-danger" id="delete_topic_reply" href=""><?php echo lang_key('delete'); ?></a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" id="delete_cancel_link"><?php echo lang_key('cancel'); ?></button>       
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the Js:

```
<!-- Delete Topic JS -->
<script>    
    function confirm_modal(delete_url)
    {
        jQuery('#deleteReplyTopic').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static',keyboard :false});
        jQuery("#deleteReplyTopic .grt").text(title);
        document.getElementById('delete_topic_reply').setAttribute("href" , delete_url );
        document.getElementById('delete_topic_reply').focus();
    }
</script>
```

And here is my Controller codes:

```
public function deletereplytopic($id='') {

        $deletereply = array(
                'id' => $id,
                'status' => 0
                );
        $deltop = 'confirmdelete';
        $this->session->set_flashdata('deltop', $deltop);   
        $this->topic_model->deleteReplyTopic($deletereply);
    }
```

This controller codes is working if I directly delete the data but if I use modal is not working..I hope someone can help me..

Comment: Do you receive an errors in the console? If you monitor the network traffic is the controller with deletereplytopic getting called/ serving an internal server error? I also don't see you sending the data or accessing the controller, just setting attributes.

Comment: Nevermind on that last sentence.

Comment: I think you are missing quotes inside e.g. `confirm_modal('something')`

Comment: I’ll try to recode this later on

Comment: Its working now I just miss this code " ' " before and after <?php echo base_url('threads/deletereplytopic/'.$toprep['id']) ?> in the click button..

Comment: glad i could help ;)

Comment: your really awesome @Alex you helped me a lot with my project..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes inside e.g. `confirm_modal('something')`

```
<a onclick="confirm_modal('<?php echo base_url('threads/deletereplytopic/'.$toprep['id']) ?>')" style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#deleteReplyTopic"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Comment: yeah thats what I did its working now hehhe thanks alex

Answer (score 0):

remove this line and it will work

```
jQuery("#deleteReplyTopic .grt").text(title);
```

its not working because title is not passes to the function

edit:
use the following for cleaner code

```
    <a  data-delurl="<?php echo base_url('threads/deletereplytopic/'.$toprep['id']) ?>" style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#deleteReplyTopic"><i class="fa fa-trash-o open-dialog" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> 


        $(document).on("click", ".open-dialog", function () {

           $("a").attr("href", $(this).data('delurl'));


        });
```

you can also use the one bellow but without argument passing

```
         $('#deleteReplyTopic').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
             //do stuff when modal opens

         });
```

Comment: really ?! I did a test using firefox and it wasn't working until commenting out that line. you better test your code in firefox